# CSS hover function stay open

Tags: html

I have code below for a couple of info boxes I have created using HTML and CSS. Is it possible to have the hover div stay open until you click the close at the bottom, and then it would slide back up and hide itself again, but just using pure CSS? Anything helps, cheers!

```js
.everything {
  text - align: center;
}

.infobox - list {
  display: inline - block;
  text - align: center;
}

ul, ol, li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list - style - position: outside;
  list - style - type: none;
}

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, ul, li, ol, form, fieldset {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

*, *: before, *: after {
  -moz - box - sizing: border - box; -
  webkit - box - sizing: border - box;
  box - sizing: border - box;
}

ul, menu, dir {
  display: block;
  list - style - type: disc; -
  webkit - margin - before: 1e m; -
  webkit - margin - after: 1e m; -
  webkit - margin - start: 0 px; -
  webkit - margin - end: 0 px; -
  webkit - padding - start: 0 px;
}

.hr {
  border - color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
  margin - left: 9 px;
  width: 210 px;
}

body {
  font - family: Arial, Helvetica, sans - serif;
  font - size: 16 px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background - color: #fcfcfc;
  color: #555;
    min-width: 20em;
}

.info-boxes li {
  width: 310px;
    height: 535px;
    background: # e2ecf6;
  border: 0 px solid# efefef;
  border - radius: 4 px;
  margin: 0 0 px 0 px;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  transform: scale(0.75);
}

.ptext {
  text - align: center;
  font - size: 20 px;

}

.profile {
  margin - top: 10 % ;
  margin - left: 1 px;
  width: 75 px;
  height: 75 px;
}

.performance {
  margin - left: 1 px;
  margin - top: 10 % ;
  width: 75 px;
  height: 75 px;
}

.learning {
  margin - top: 10 % ;
  width: 75 px;
  height: 75 px;
}

.team {
  margin - top: 10 % ;
  width: 75 px;
  height: 75 px;
}

.smallicons {
  width: 50 px;
  height: 50 px;
}

.profileclose {
  margin - top: 215 px;
}

.infobox - list li {
  display: inline - block;
}

a {
  color: white;
  text - decoration: none;
  font - weight: lighter;
}

.info - boxes li.infobox {
    display: table - cell;
    text - align: center;
    vertical - align: middle;
    height: 535 px;
    width: 310 px;
  }

  .info - boxes li.infobox: before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left: 20 % ;
    width: 160 % ;
    height: 188 % ;
    background - color: rgb(255, 255, 255); /* fallback */
    background - color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
    top: 0; -
    webkit - transform: rotate(46 deg); -
    moz - transform: rotate(46 deg);
    transform: rotate(30 deg);
  }

  .info - boxes li: hover.shade {
    animation - name: windowshade;
    cursor: pointer;
  }

  .info - boxes li.shade,
  .info - boxes li: hover.shade {
    animation - timing - function: cubic - bezier(0.215, 0.61, 0.355, 1);
    animation - duration: 1 s;
    animation - iteration - count: 1;
    animation - fill - mode: forwards;
  }

section p {
  line - height: 1.3e m;
  color: #6d6e71;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0 10px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  text-align:left;
}

p {
  display: block;
}

.info-boxes li .shade {
  position: absolute;
  width: 310px;
  height: 555px;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  background-color: # 00688 B;
  color: #fff;
  display: table;
  vertical - align: middle;
  padding: 20 px 10 px 0;
  transform: translateY(-340 px);
  animation - name: windowshade - out;
}

.info - boxes li.shade h3 {
    color: #fff;
    padding: 10 px;
    font - weight: bold
  }

  .info - boxes li.shade p {
    color: #fff;
    line - height: 3e m;
    font - weight: lighter;
  }

  .ie9.info - boxes li: hover.shade {
    top: 245 px
  }

  .info - boxes li: hover a {
    text - decoration: none
  }

@keyframes windowshade {
  0 % {
    transform: translateY(-535 px)
  }
  100 % {
    transform: translateY(0)
  }
}

@keyframes windowshade - out {
  0 % {
    transform: translateY(0)
  }
  100 % {
    transform: translateY(-535 px)
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="everything">
  <br style="line-height:100px;">
  <section class="info-boxes">
    <ul class="infobox-list">
      <li>
        <a href="#">
          <div class="infobox">
            <table>
              <tr>
                <img class="profile" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/djxai1v1e/image/upload/v1497365894/Profile-Icon_twnm83.png"></tr>
              <tr>
                <p class="ptext">Profile</p>
              </tr>
            </table>
          </div>
          <div class="shade">
            <table>
              <tr>
                <td>
                  <img class="smallicons" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/djxai1v1e/image/upload/v1497301295/About-Me_dudglr.png">
                </td>
                <td>
                  <p>About Me</p>
                  <hr class="hr">
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td><img class="smallicons" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/djxai1v1e/image/upload/v1497284615/Resume_tb7t02.png"> </td>
                  <td>
                    <p>Resume</p>
                    <hr class="hr">
                  </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td><img class="smallicons" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/djxai1v1e/image/upload/v1497280574/Accountabilities_qfdcns.png"> </td>
                  <td>
                    <p>Accountabilities
                      <p/>
                      <hr class="hr">
                  </td>
              </tr>
            </table>
            <div class="profileclose">Close</div>
          </div>
        </a>
      </li>

      <li>
        <a href="#">
          <div class="infobox">
            <table>
              <tr>
                <img class="performance" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/djxai1v1e/image/upload/v1497365894/Performance-Icon_bwevmx.png"></tr>
              <tr>
                <p class="ptext">Performance</p>
              </tr>
            </table>
          </div>
          <div class="shade">
            <table>
              <tr>
                <td>
                  <img class="smallicons" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/djxai1v1e/image/upload/v1497284615/Goals_aw4nso.png">
                </td>
                <td>
                  <p>Goals</p>
                  <hr class="hr">
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td><img class="smallicons" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/djxai1v1e/image/upload/v1497284934/EA_n8lvj1.png" </td>
                  <td>
                    <p>Effectiveness Assessment</p>
                    <hr class="hr">
                  </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td><img class="smallicons" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/djxai1v1e/image/upload/v1497284615/development_yfv6o1.png" </td>
                  <td>
                    <p>Development Plan</p>
                    <hr class="hr">
                  </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td><img class="smallicons" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/djxai1v1e/image/upload/v1497285433/resources_b3r88g.png"> </td>
                  <td>
                    <p>Resources
                      <p/>
                      <hr class="hr">
                  </td>
              </tr>
            </table>
          </div>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="infobox">
          <table>
            <tr>
              <img class="learning" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/djxai1v1e/image/upload/v1497365894/Learning-Icon_p8gqbk.png"></tr>
            <tr>
              <p class="ptext">Learning</p>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </div>
        <div class="shade">
          <table>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <img class="smallicons" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/djxai1v1e/image/upload/v1497297687/Training-Plan_v43ne7.png">
              </td>
              <td>
                <p>Training Plan</p>
                <hr class="hr">
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><img class="smallicons" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/djxai1v1e/image/upload/v1497297687/Training-History_czttv1.png"> </td>
                <td>
                  <p>Training History</p>
                  <hr class="hr">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><img class="smallicons" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/djxai1v1e/image/upload/v1497298863/coursefeedback_qdh1wm.png"> </td>
                <td>
                  <p>Course Feedback</p>
                  <hr class="hr">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><img class="smallicons" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/djxai1v1e/image/upload/v1497299106/Favourites_y9gkce.png"> </td>
                <td>
                  <p>Training Favourites
                    <p/>
                    <hr class="hr">
                </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </div>
   
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="infobox">
          <table>
            <tr>
              <img class="team" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/djxai1v1e/image/upload/v1497365894/TeamIcon_as9ynw.png"></tr>
            <tr>
              <p class="ptext">Team</p>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </div>
        <div class="shade">
          <table>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <img class="smallicons" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/djxai1v1e/image/upload/v1497300652/Team_iovnl5.png">
              </td>
              <td>
                <p>Team</p>
                <hr class="hr">
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><img class="smallicons" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/djxai1v1e/image/upload/v1497284615/Goals_aw4nso.png"> </td>
                <td>
                  <p>Team Goals</p>
                  <hr class="hr">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><img class="smallicons" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/djxai1v1e/image/upload/v1497284615/development_yfv6o1.png"> </td>
                <td>
                  <p>Team Development</p>
                  <hr class="hr">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><img class="smallicons" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/djxai1v1e/image/upload/v1497297687/Training-Plan_v43ne7.png"> </td>
                <td>
                  <p>Team Training</p>
                  <hr class="hr">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><img class="smallicons" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/djxai1v1e/image/upload/v1497301295/Approval_f9y1da.png"> </td>
                <td>
                  <p>Approvals
                    <p/>
                    <hr class="hr">
                </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </div>

      </li>
    </ul>
  </section>
</div>
```

Comment: .. not without javascript

Comment: As far as I know, there is no way to do with only CSS. If you were to manipulate the DOM some way (via JS, etc) then you could add a CSS class to keep the element visible. And then you could remove the class on some event to hide it again.

Comment: Yeah, you can do this with only CSS but there are about a zillion errors in the code you supplied.

Comment: @Gerard Sorry about that! I'm pretty new to CSS and HTML!

Comment: I'll make a simple example using CSS only. Then you can adjust it to your liking later.

Comment: @Gerard Sounds good! Thanks.

Comment: Looks like I spoke too soon. The hover part won't do it.

Answer (score 0):

To the best of my knowledge it is not possible to do what you're describing in pure CSS on `:hover`.

---

It is however possible to do something similar with clicks by using `id`s and [`:target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:target), though it can get complicated depending what you want it to do and you can only have one open at once.

> The :target CSS pseudo-class represents a unique element (the target element) with an id matching the URL's fragment.
>
> – https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:target

Here is a basic example of what I am describing.

```css
ul div {
  padding: 1em;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  display: none;
}
ul div a {
  font-size: 0.8em;
  padding: 0.5em 0.5em 0;
  display: block;
}
ul div:target {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="#menu-1">Menu Item 1</a>
    <div id="menu-1">
      Expanded content 1
      <a href="#">close</a>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#menu-2">Menu Item 2</a>
    <div id="menu-2">
      Expanded content 2
      <a href="#">close</a>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#menu-3">Menu Item 3</a>
    <div id="menu-3">
      Expanded content 3
      <a href="#">close</a>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

with javascript it's almost not difficult, but you have to add unique identifiers to each info div and you can use the onmouseover attributes in html to call a javascript function:

```
<ul>
  <li>
<a  onmouseover="show_info('menu-1')">Menu Item 1</a>
    <div id="menu-1">
      Expanded content 1
      <a href="javascript:close('menu-1')">close</a>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a onmouseover="show_info('menu-2')">Menu Item 2</a>
    <div id="menu-2">
      Expanded content 2
      <a href="javascript:close('menu-2')">close</a>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a onmouseover="show_info('menu-3')">Menu Item 3</a>
    <div id="menu-3">
      Expanded content 3
      <a href="javascript:close('menu-3')">close</a>
    </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
```

the close buttons are calling js functions too, to close the div.
for this you just need two simple js functions:

```
function show_info(name) {
var element = document.getElementById(name);
element.style.display = "block";
}
function close(name) {
    var element = document.getElementById(name);
    element.style.display = "none";
}
```

and don't forget to style the info divs with css by default to not be displayed ( `display: none;` ) (recommend to use classes). And sorry for my english

Comment: If you want to, open them just if you click the link, simply replace 'onmouseover' with 'href'.

Comment: Could you try doing this w my code, I cant seem to get it to work

Comment: Yeah wait, i will post an second answer shortly

Answer (score -1):

here is the adapt to your site, you just have to adjust the css, because the hight properties are no longer in charge and if the `.infobox` is displayed, the `li`'s are floating to the bottom (I don't know why).
Here is the code:

```
<style>
.everything {
  text-align: center;
}

.infobox-list {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
}

ul, ol, li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-position: outside;
  list-style-type: none;
}

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, ul, li, ol, form, fieldset {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

*, *:before, *:after {
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box; 
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

ul, menu, dir {
  display: block;
  list-style-type: disc; 
  -webkit-margin-before: 1em; 
  -webkit-margin-after: 1em; 
  -webkit-margin-start: 0 px; 
  -webkit-margin-end: 0 px; 
  -webkit-padding-start: 0 px;
}

.hr {
  border-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
  margin-left: 9 px;
  width: 210 px;
}

body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 16 px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #fcfcfc;
  color: #555;
    min-width: 20em;
}

.info-boxes li {
  width: 310px;
  background: #e2ecf6;
  border: 0px solid #efefef;
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin: 0 0px 0px;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  transform: scale(0.75);
}

.ptext {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;

}

.profile {
  margin-top: 10%;
  margin-left: 1px;
  width: 75 px;
  height: 75 px;
}

.performance {
  margin-left: 1px;
  margin-top: 10% ;
  width: 75 px;
  height: 75 px;
}

.learning {
  margin-top: 10% ;
  width: 75 px;
  height: 75 px;
}

.team {
  margin-top: 10% ;
  width: 75 px;
  height: 75 px;
}

.smallicons {
  width: 50 px;
  height: 50 px;
}

.profileclose {
  margin-top: 0px;
  color: #6d6e71;
}

.infobox-list li {
  display: inline-block;
}
.infobox {
    display: none;
}

a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: lighter;
}

.info-boxes li.infobox {
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 310 px;
}

  .info-boxes li.infobox:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left: 20 % ;
    width: 160 % ;
    height: 188 % ;
    background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); /* fallback */
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
    top: 0; 
    -webkit-transform: rotate(46deg); 
    -moz-transform: rotate(46deg);
    transform: rotate(30deg);
  }

  .info-boxes li:hover.shade {
    animation-name: windowshade;
    cursor: pointer;
  }

  .info-boxes li.shade,
  .info-boxes li:hover.shade {
    animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.61, 0.355, 1);
    animation-duration: 1s;
    animation-iteration-count: 1;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  }

section p {
  line-height: 1.3em;
  color: #6d6e71;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0 10px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  text-align:left;
}

p {
  display: block;
}

.info-boxes li.shade {
  position: absolute;
  width: 310px;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  background-color: #00688B;
  color: #fff;
  display: table;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding: 20 px 10 px 0;
  transform: translateY(-340 px);
  animation-name: windowshade-out;
}

.info-boxes li.shade h3 {
    color: #fff;
    padding: 10 px;
    font-weight: bold;
  }

  .info-boxes li.shade p {
    color: #fff;
    line-height: 3em;
    font-weight: lighter;
  }

  .ie9.info-boxes li:hover.shade {
    top: 245px;
  }

  .info-boxes li:hover a {
    text-decoration: none;
  }

@keyframes windowshade {
  0 % {
    transform: translateY(-535 px);
  }
  100 % {
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
}

@keyframes windowshade-out {
  0 % {
    transform: translateY(0)
  }
  100 % {
    transform: translateY(-535 px)
  }
}
</style>
<body>

<div class="everything">
<script>
    function show_info(name) {
        var element = document.getElementById(name);
        element.style.display = "block";
    }
    function close(name) {
        var element = document.getElementById(name);
        element.style.display = "none";
    }
</script>
  <br style="line-height:100px;">
  <section class="info-boxes">
    <ul class="infobox-list"><li>
        <div class="infobox" id="info-1">
            <table>
              <tr>
                <img class="profile" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/djxai1v1e/image/upload/v1497365894/Profile-Icon_twnm83.png"></tr>
              <tr>
                <p class="ptext">Profile</p>
              </tr>
            </table>
          </div>
        <a onmouseover="show_info('info-1')">
          <div class="shade">
            <table>
              <tr>
                <td>
                  <img class="smallicons" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/djxai1v1e/image/upload/v1497301295/About-Me_dudglr.png">
                </td>
                <td>
                  <p>About Me</p>
                  <hr class="hr">
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td><img class="smallicons" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/djxai1v1e/image/upload/v1497284615/Resume_tb7t02.png"> </td>
                  <td>
                    <p>Resume</p>
                    <hr class="hr">
                  </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td><img class="smallicons" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/djxai1v1e/image/upload/v1497280574/Accountabilities_qfdcns.png"> </td>
                  <td>
                    <p>Accountabilities
                      <p/>
                      <hr class="hr">
                  </td>
              </tr>
            </table>
            <a class="profileclose" href="javascript:close('info-1')">Close</a>
          </div>
        </a>
      </li><li>
        <div class="infobox" id="info-2">
            <table>
              <tr>
                <img class="performance" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/djxai1v1e/image/upload/v1497365894/Performance-Icon_bwevmx.png"></tr>
              <tr>
                <p class="ptext">Performance</p>
              </tr>
            </table>
          </div>
        <a onmouseover="show_info('info-2')">

          <div class="shade">
            <table>
              <tr>
                <td>
                  <img class="smallicons" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/djxai1v1e/image/upload/v1497284615/Goals_aw4nso.png">
                </td>
                <td>
                  <p>Goals</p>
                  <hr class="hr">
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td><img class="smallicons" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/djxai1v1e/image/upload/v1497284934/EA_n8lvj1.png" </td>
                  <td>
                    <p>Effectiveness Assessment</p>
                    <hr class="hr">
                  </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td><img class="smallicons" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/djxai1v1e/image/upload/v1497284615/development_yfv6o1.png" </td>
                  <td>
                    <p>Development Plan</p>
                    <hr class="hr">
                  </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td><img class="smallicons" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/djxai1v1e/image/upload/v1497285433/resources_b3r88g.png"> </td>
                  <td>
                    <p>Resources
                      <p/>
                      <hr class="hr">
                  </td>
              </tr>
            </table>
          </div>
        </a>
      </li><li>
      <div class="infobox" id="info-3">
          <table>
            <tr>
              <img class="learning" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/djxai1v1e/image/upload/v1497365894/Learning-Icon_p8gqbk.png"></tr>
            <tr>
              <p class="ptext">Learning</p>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </div>
        <a onmouseover="show_info('info-3')">
        <div class="shade">
          <table>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <img class="smallicons" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/djxai1v1e/image/upload/v1497297687/Training-Plan_v43ne7.png">
              </td>
              <td>
                <p>Training Plan</p>
                <hr class="hr">
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><img class="smallicons" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/djxai1v1e/image/upload/v1497297687/Training-History_czttv1.png"> </td>
                <td>
                  <p>Training History</p>
                  <hr class="hr">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><img class="smallicons" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/djxai1v1e/image/upload/v1497298863/coursefeedback_qdh1wm.png"> </td>
                <td>
                  <p>Course Feedback</p>
                  <hr class="hr">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><img class="smallicons" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/djxai1v1e/image/upload/v1497299106/Favourites_y9gkce.png"> </td>
                <td>
                  <p>Training Favourites
                    </p>
                    <hr class="hr">
                </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </div>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="infobox" id="info-4">
          <table>
            <tr>
              <img class="team" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/djxai1v1e/image/upload/v1497365894/TeamIcon_as9ynw.png"></tr>
            <tr>
              <p class="ptext">Team</p>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </div>
        <div class="shade">
        <a onmouseover="show_info('info-4')" onmouseleave="close('info-4')">
          <table>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <img class="smallicons" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/djxai1v1e/image/upload/v1497300652/Team_iovnl5.png">
              </td>
              <td>
                <p>Team</p>
                <hr class="hr">
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><img class="smallicons" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/djxai1v1e/image/upload/v1497284615/Goals_aw4nso.png"> </td>
                <td>
                  <p>Team Goals</p>
                  <hr class="hr">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><img class="smallicons" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/djxai1v1e/image/upload/v1497284615/development_yfv6o1.png"> </td>
                <td>
                  <p>Team Development</p>
                  <hr class="hr">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><img class="smallicons" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/djxai1v1e/image/upload/v1497297687/Training-Plan_v43ne7.png"> </td>
                <td>
                  <p>Team Training</p>
                  <hr class="hr">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><img class="smallicons" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/djxai1v1e/image/upload/v1497301295/Approval_f9y1da.png"> </td>
                <td>
                  <p>Approvals</p>
                    <hr class="hr">
                </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </div>
            </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </section>
</div>
</body>
```

to hide the icon, after the mouse has left the `li`, clone the onmouseleave event of the fourth box, to the others and just the js function parameters. Otherwise, you will have to add the close `<a>` of the first box to the other boxes, and just it's parameters. **Note: in css, spaces are important! Do not add some random (in hex colours f.e.) and also don't add some before and after '-', because the browser has to detect whole strings like `-webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;`, not like: `- webkit - animations - iteration - count: 1;`, because this way actually isn't working.**
hope you are getting along with the rest of your project well.
**mmi**